Не работают сокращения Emmet в SASS-файлах (VS Code)
Проблема в том, что пытаюсь разобраться с работой в Visual Studio Code. Ранее всегда работал с SASS для вёрстки, и не хочется отказываться.
Проблема в том, что не работают сокращения Emmet в SASS-файлах:

Установил расширение Sass (.sass only) v1.8.31 для подсветки синтаксиса;
Сделал дополнительные настройки в settings.json:

json
{
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "sass": "css"
    },
    "emmet.preferences": {
        "sass.propertyEnd": "",
    }
}

После всех этих манипуляций, к сожалению, сокращения Emmet не работают, хотя в документации указана поддержка sass.
Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема?
